# Java Bouncy Castle TLS Protocol version order?

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm using the Java Bouncy Castle TLS library (bctls-jdk15to18-1.68.jar). When I call `SSLContext.getInstance`, I specify "TLS" and the BCJSSE provider:

```java
final SSLContext context    =   SSLContext.getInstance("TLS",BCJSSE);
                 context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), keyStoreSalter);
logger.debug(Arrays.toString(context.getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()));
```

When I query the SupportedSSLParameters of the context, it returns: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3]

As the client, are all of these versions communicated to the server, and the server chooses the highest that it supports?

If I denote a specific version `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3",BCJSSE);`
and the server does not support that version is an exception thrown?

I'm trying to determine why you would ever specify a version in your call, if the negotiation will automagically determine the best match.

EDIT: Added so this is attached:
[Perfect test site for TLS/SSL](https://badssl.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the client, are all of these versions communicated to the server, and the server chooses the highest that it supports?

The client simply tells which versions are supported (TLS 1.3 `supported_versions` extension) or announces the best it can do (TLS 1.2 and lower). The server then simply picks the highest protocol version which is supported by both client and server.

> If I denote a specific version SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3",BCJSSE); and the server does not support that version is an exception thrown?

If there is no common protocol version supported by both client and server then the handshake will fail and an exception thrown.

> I'm trying to determine why you would ever specify a version in your call, if the negotiation will automagically determine the best match.

This will usually only be done if there is a requirement to not support versions below a specific one, i.e. support only TLS 1.2 and higher. Since TLS 1.0 is considered too weak already in some situations, this can be a real-world requirement.

Comment: If I call SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3",BCJSSE), what is communicated to the server? And if the server doesn't support TLSv1.3, does that throw an exception, in which case I can catch that exception and try again with SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2",BCJSSE) on down the line? If the client communicates what versions it supports and the server chooses the highest it supports, then that's what I mean by order of precedence.

Comment: I'll edit my question to make my meaning more technically accurate.

Comment: @ZacWolf: does the answer now fits what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Yes, thanks! (Minor edit: "to weak" = "too weak", and maybe reword the last bit? "TLS 1.0 is already considered too weak, and in some use cases so is TLS 1.1."

Answer (score 1):

"Supported" in the context of the JSSE API means that it is supported by this JSSE implementation and thus COULD be enabled, but NOT that it is enabled by default. If you want to see the actual protocols enabled on a new `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine`, call the `getEnabledProtocols` method on it.

You can then experiment with which of the "supported" protocols are actually auto-enabled depending on the algorithm you used to construct the `SSLContext`. Notably specifying just "TLS" will not automatically enable TLSv1.3 in v1.68 (since it's the first release to support TLSv1.3 and we are being cautious). Also SSLv3 is never automatically enabled.

Regardless of how you created the `SSLContext`, the enabled protocols can then be modified either through `SSLSocket/SSLEngine .setEnabledProtocols`, or through `SSLParameters.setProtocols`.

All of the ENABLED protocols are communicated to the server, and the server chooses the highest that it supports. (Roughly speaking; some servers may negotiate the cipher suite first, and then check for a suitable protocol version).

You should configure your socket with all the versions you want to support and just try one call. It is not advisable to try one version at a time since it may expose you to a [downgrade attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downgrade_attack).

Comment: Thank you for this information! So I could add ```socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.3", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"});``` if I (as the client) wanted to let the server know that these are the protocols I'm willing to work with? [Assuming that these entries are included in the ```context.getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()``` as "supported" to being with]

Comment: Yes, or you could use SSLSocket.getSupportedProtocols instead. It might also be worth reading/scanning the JSSE Reference Guide for an overview: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html .